# What values when passed as a parameter to a function will cause default values to be used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I'm trying to simplify some of my code and am wondering which values when passed as a parameter to a function cause that parameter to default to it set value (as defined in the `def` statement). Example:

In one of my classes I have the following function

```
def scrape(self, search_term='animals'):
```

What value(s) other than no value at all can be passed to the `scrape` function that will cause the function to use it's default value (animals)?

In the following function in my main class I call the function with a variable that is by default set to `None`, which I was thinking would cause `scrape` to use `animals`, but it actually sets `search_term=None`

```
def list_channels(query=None):
    live_source = exploreorg.Site()
    links = live_source.scrape(query)
```

Is there some value I can pass to the `scrape` function that will enable this behavior or is my only option to do an if/else?

```
def list_channels(query=None):
    live_source = exploreorg.Site()
    if query is None:
        links = live_source.scrape()
    else:
        links = live_source.scrape(query)
```

I feel like that is so bulky, but if it's the best way, then I'm ok with it. I imagine there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Only if you don't pass any value will the default value be used.

Comment: Just don't use default arguments, and you wouldn't need these `if/else` statements.

Comment: You can of course pass the actual default value, if that helps you.

Comment: Why can't you have query='animals' as your default for list_channels?  That's what your latter example does, only much less "bulky"

Comment: Also, you only need defaults if you want users to be able to use the function without that particular argument given.  I'd advise not using a default argument in either case.  Your code will be more readable if you require these search terms to be passed in every use case.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard you're right, I hadn't even thought of that since I originally made list_channels prior to creating the scrape function (in a different module). That seems like the most logical and readable solution. So, now I have `def list_channels(query='animals')`, then `links = exploreorg.Site().scrape(query)`, which calls `def scrape(self, search_term):`. Is that correct? Please do create an answer so I can give you proper credit :)

Comment: It's amazing what people can accomplish when none of them are concerned with credit.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses the default value only when no value is passed. To avoid repeating the value, maybe you can use `None` as the default value?

```
def scrape(self, search_term=None):
  search_term = search_term or 'animals'

def list_channels(query=None):
  live_source = exploreorg.Site()
  links = live_source.scrape(query)
```

Or reuse a variable?

```
DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM = 'animals'
def scrape(self, search_term=DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM):
  ...

def list_channels(query=DEFAULT_SEARCH_TERM):
  live_source = exploreorg.Site()
  links = live_source.scrape(query)
```

Comment: For the first option, I'd rather not have to define the variable inside the function. For the second option, this wouldn't work since the `scrape` & `list_channels` functions are in different modules/files.

Comment: Why don't you want to define the variable inside the function? What's wrong?